# How to create a hotspot in ubuntu 20.10 using the BCM43142

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.10

I am unable to create a hotspot in Ubuntu 20.10 properly. While there's an option to create hotspot in this Ubuntu version but if I create it then I can see the SSID on my phone and if I try to connect it then it doesn't ask for any password and hence, I am not able to connect it.

I can only create a hotspot with WEP security only. I didn't get any other option for security. When I see the created hotspot in mobile phone, it doesn't have any security and when I try to connect to it then nothing happens.

My adapter does not support AP (master) mode

I also tried to create an hotspot using command `nm-connection-editor`. I created the hotspot successfully but the created hotspot is not visible in the visible network section. I can connect to other Wi-Fi connection but not able create a hotspot. I want to create hotspot and share my ethernet connection to hotspot.

```
$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n 
(rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208BM [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev ff)
```

Comment: Hotspot needs an adapter that supports "AP (master) mode" 
 (ie. an access point) See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode for some pointers. Looks like the newest method is to do `iw list | grep AP`  and see it it includes AP

Comment: Do you have `wpasupplicant` installed?

Comment: yes i have wpasupplicant installed.

Answer (score 1):

To create a hotspot (Internet sharing through Wi-Fi), you can use  [linux-wifi-hotspot](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot) providing a GUI Wi-Fi Hotspot and a CLI `create_ap`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lakinduakash/lwh
sudo apt install linux-wifi-hotspot
wihotspot
```

**Edit**:

If you get the following error:

```
 ERROR: Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode
```

That's mean your Wi-Fi card doesn't support the AP mode, you have to use a USB Wi-Fi dongle or change your PCI card.

The BCM43142 should work with `brcmsmac` driver which support the AP mode. Install the `firmware-b43-installer` package:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Load the `brcmsmac` driver:

```
sudo modprobe -rv wl b43  ssb
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

Comment: after running wihotspot i got this error : ERROR: Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode

Comment: I was running windows 10 and there my Network adapter was working fine. I was able to create hotspot. Now after installing ubuntu, I don't know why my network adapter doesn't work properly. I have loaded the brcmsmac driver but my problem is not solved yet. I am facing the same problem. If there is another method then it will be very helpful.