# How to use only USB Wi-Fi card and make a hotspot from the built-in Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless, usb, sharing, ap-hotspot, dongle

I am trying to use my laptop as a hotspot. I do not have a LAN cable however, but only a USB Wi-Fi card (Netgear A6150).

I am trying to Turn-off the built-in Wi-Fi, get internet from the USB card only, and then share the connection via Hotspot from the built-in card.

I followed the discussion in [How to disable built-in Wi-Fi and use only USB Wi-Fi card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168032/how-to-disable-built-in-wi-fi-and-use-only-usb-wi-fi-card). I can disable my built-in card via editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and then doing `sudo service network-manager restart`.
But then, problem is, my built-in Wi-Fi becomes completely unusable. Or at least I do not know if/how to do anything with it.

So, again question is, how can I use my built-in Wi-Fi card as a hotspot, while getting connection from the USB. As a small note, previously I was using LAN cable and I was able to turn on hotspot from my laptop, so turning it on, should be possible.

Comment: If you want to share from the internal card, why would you turn it off? This seems illogical … 

Comment: If both are enabled, I cannot turn on the wifi-hotspot, so I tried by turning the connection off.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327718/how-to-create-a-hotspot-in-ubuntu-20-10-using-the-bcm43142/1327724#1327724